Gravity in relation to quantum field theory?
It's probably simple for you guys and ladies to answer - but where does gravity sit in relation to quantum field theory/quantum mechanics etc?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See this question for a more specific take on how general relativity and quantum mechanics are (in)compatible.

There is no accepted quantum theory of gravity. General Relativity is a classical field theory.
